# Remove a particular character from each line of a file if that occurs

Tags: java

Here's the problem. I have some text in my .txt file, it look exactly like this:

```
Bee-bee is the voice that Sheep giv-
e. Mou-Mou is the voice that Cow gi-
ve. Miau-Miau is the voice that Ca-
t gives.
```

Program that I need reading this file and connect line. Output (txt.file):

```
Bee-bee is the voice that Sheep give. Mou-Mou is the voice that Cow give. Miau-Miau is the voice that Cat gives.
```

I think I need to do something like this:

```
//Locate the file:
File file = new File("/path/to/file.txt");

//Create a temporary file
File temp = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt", file.getParentFile());

//String I want to remove
String delete = "-";

//open the file, open the tmp file, read the file line by line and replacing signs
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    // ...
}

//Delete the string from the line.    
line = line.replace(delete, "");
```

Here's a problem that it replace "Bee-bee" with "beebee" in output file and that is not what I want. I need some construction "if the sign is "-" and the next sign is carriage return, delete "-" but I have no idea how to write this.

Comment: You can put a carriage return in a string like this: `"\r"`.  Usually though a line ends with a new line: `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

The String that you get back from `readLine` is going to a the whole line **up to** the linefeed character.

i.e.

> Bee-bee is the voice that Sheep giv-

so all you need to test is that the last char is `-`  and if it is return a substring up to that point.

You can make use of the tradional `lastIndexOf` and `substring` or `endswith` or you could split the String using a regex pattern of `-$`

An example is

```
    String line = "Bee-bee is the voice that Sheep giv-";
    if (line.endsWith("-")) {
        String output = line.substring(0, line.length() -1);
        System.out.println(output);
        // maybe append to a StringBuilder ?
        stringBuf.append (output);
    }
```

These substrings could then be appended to a StringBuilder so that you end up with the entire String as you want it.

Comment: If this answer meets your need please upvote and/or accept this answer